# Forever stop server.js returns "server.js is not a valid index for a forever process."

Tags: node.js, sudo, forever

I inherited a server and I'm having an odd issue. I was having a problem when running `forever start server.js` in which it didn't return a message, and then `forever list` didn't show any forever processes running. After some digging I found that some people suggested running forever as `sudo`.

After I ran `sudo forever start server.js` it seemed to fire up just fine, and `forever list` shows server.js as running. However, now I cannot stop the process. Running `kill` removes node from the list displayed at `top`, but Forever still views server.js as running. Running `sudo forever stop server.js` returns the error "server.js is not a valid index for a forever process." Running `sudo forever stopall` or `sudo forever list` returns

```
node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
    at Argv (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/optimist/0.1.2/package/lib/optimist.js:38:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/forever/0.3.0/package/bin/forever:81:26)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at loadModule (node.js:283:14)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/bin/forever:11:18)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
```

No matter what I do, I can't stop server.js. I guess forever is being a little overzealous in it's mission. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why this worked, but for some reason it solved my problem. Well not entirely, but partially. When I `su root` and then run the forever commands, I am able to `start` and `stopall` without a hitch. Still getting the same error for `forever stop server.js`, so for whatever reason I'm unable to stop the server that way, but I got around it by being able to run `forever stopall` as `su root`.

Comment: This worked because you're starting the forever process as a root process. Indeed, if you type `ps aux | grep forever | grep -v grep` in a command prompt, you would see that the owner of the process is root. Only root can start/stop the process.

Comment: Okay I see. I figured that running it with `sudo` would function in the same way. I'm figuring this out as I go along, so I appreciate the explanation. Still doesn't explain why it's not accepting `forever stop server.js` as a valid command though. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: What is the value of the last column of the output of `ps aux | grep 'server.js' | grep -v grep`?

Comment: There's two lines. Last column of the first line is `/usr/local/bin/forever start server.js`, and for the second line `server.js`.